# I am trying to run unittest using python. But, when I try to run the below code, I get error even though I have handled the exception

Tags: python-3.x, exception, python-unittest

```
import unittest
import math

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
        # Define the initialization method below
        try:
            if not isinstance(radius, (int, float)):
                raise TypeError
        except TypeError:
            print("radius must be a number")
        try:
            if radius in range(0, 1001):
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive")

    def area(self):
        return round(math.pi * self.radius ** 2, 2)

    def circumference(self):
        return round(2 * math.pi * self.radius)


class TestCircleCreation(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_creating_circle_with_numeric_radius(self):
        # Define a circle 'c1' with radius 2.5 and check if
        # the value of c1.radius equal to 2.5 or not
        c1 = Circle(2.5)
        self.assertEqual(2.5, c1.radius)

    def test_creating_circle_with_negative_radius(self):
        # Try Defining a circle 'c' with radius -2.5 and see
        # if it raises a ValueError with the message
        # "radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive"
        c2 = Circle(-2.5)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, c2)

    def test_creating_circle_with_greaterthan_radius(self):
        # Try Defining a circle 'c' with radius 1000.1 and see
        # if it raises a ValueError with the message
        # "radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive"
        c3 = Circle(1000.1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, c3)

    def test_creating_circle_with_nonnumeric_radius(self):
        # Try Defining a circle 'c' with radius 'hello' and see
        # if it raises a TypeError with the message
        # "radius must be a number"
        c4 = Circle("hello")
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, c4)
```

Comment: What error? You're catching `ValueError`s, but you're also asserting that they'll be thrown. I'm guessing you're getting `AssertionError`s? And why are you throwing in a `try` block the same exception that the `try` is catching?

Comment: I am getting 'TypeError: 'Circle' object is not callable' for two of the above tests:  'test_creating_circle_with_negative_radius' and 'test_creating_circle_with_greaterthan_radius'.

Comment: In the future, please format your code and add adequate description of your errors. Making it difficult for people to help you isn't a good way to get help.

Comment: This is the first question I have asked on Stack as I am new to programming. I'll try to phrase my questions more clearly in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`assertRaises` expects a function for it's second parameter.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) You're passing a `Circle` object though, which it's attempting to call as a function; which is causing that error.

I think you meant something like:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, lambda: Circle(-2.5))
```

Then make a similar change to the other cases.

This wraps the call to the `Circle` constructor in a `lambda` function so `assertRaises` can call the constructor as needed.

---

This will still fail as you're using a `try` to catch the `ValueError` and `TypeError`s that `assertRaises` is looking for. If you want the exceptions to be thrown, don't catch them internally.

Comment: So why is the test 'test_creating_circle_with_nonnumeric_radius' working? Since I have used the same logic there as well.

Comment: @TejaswaYadav I don't think it is working. I think the script is failing before that code executes, so that function is never being run.

Comment: it is working. Two of the above tests are working and get passed. 'test_creating_circle_with_numeric_radius' and 'test_creating_circle_with_nonnumeric_radius' are working fine.

Comment: @TejaswaYadav The test case using `assertEquals` will work because it doesn't expect a function. And the `TypeError` test may actually seem to work because, as you noted in the comment, attempting to call a non-function as a function raises a `TypeError`, which you're having `assertRaises` check for. It's raising the `TypeError` because of a bad argument to `assertRaises` though, not because your code is correctly raising the error. The test is passing incorrectly.

Comment: Okay. So how do I rectify this Error?

Comment: @TejaswaYadav That is what my answer addresses.